# Why do the whipped egg white and syrup for my sorbet not combine?

Tags: eggs, egg-whites, sorbet

For some fruit sorbet recipes, eg lemon sorbet, the recipe has three fundamental components:

- a syrup (maybe cooked with lemon zest etc)
- the juice of your fruit
- whipped egg whites

It is simple: Prepare all three ingredients, allow them to cool down, carefully mix together and fill the mixture into the ice machine. My problem is: The egg white will not combine with the juice and syrup. During freezing I'll get a very unpleasant and inhomogenous texture as a result.

Does anyone know why the egg whites won't combine and what I can do to fix this?

Comment: how "whipped" are your egg whites? Stiff peaks, soft peaks, something else?

Comment: I usually whip them to stiff peaks for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply whipped eggwhites are not especially stable, and don't have a nice texture. They are OK to be used in some applications, but rarely the best option.

Given that you already have syrup here, what I would do is an Italian meringue. For that, you stream the hot syrup (115 C/240F) into the mixer while whipping the egg whites, and do it long enough to get a glossy, small-bubbled foam. It is a much more stable substance, with friendlier behavior.

I haven't tried diluting Italian meringue with fruit juice, but frankly, I imagine that sorbet made with fruit juice won't be especially good, because of the high amount of crystals. I always use puréed fruit for sorbets, which works very nicely. It should be not so difficult to first [fold](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4589/what-does-it-mean-to-fold-in-an-ingredient-into-a-mix) some purée into the meringue, then fold the mixture back into the remaining purée.

Comment: have you seen this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HsMzE2MwN8o

Comment: @Luciano no, I didn't know it. Interesting claim, I would have to experiment with it.

Comment: I've watched it and it sounds interesting, haven't tried myself too. Let me know if you do!

Comment: This worked very well both for a lemon and a cranberry sorbet.
The fruit juice was part of a lemon sorbet recipe, which I have simply tossed, as your answer regarding juice makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I don't typically use egg white in my sorbets, but the advice I see is to whip 1 egg white per batch to fairly stiff peaks, then add slowly near the end of the churning process, until incorporated, when the sorbet is almost ready for the freezer. Churn a few minutes more...freeze.  It sounds like you may be trying to combine before freezing.